# Is it possible to make one graph importing another using rdfDotNet

Tags: c#, semantic-web, ontology, dotnetrdf

Is it possible to make one graph importing another using [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/)?

A brief explanation: I want to store many graphs, filled up with class individuals. I need achieve situation in which only one of these graphs stores all class and property definitions, and all other graphs stores only class and properties individuals. At the moment I can store ontology schema in all graphs with individuals and it leads to a monstrous nodes duplication.

Comment: No there isn't and I'm not sure why you need this functionality?  There is no reason to store your ontology schema in all your graphs in the first place.  It would be better if your question explained why you need to do this as if we knew the why there may be an alternative way to achieve your aim

Comment: @RobV, I have one large schema and huge number of separate graphs filled with class individuals. I chose this model because sometimes I need to query all data with sparql and sometimes I need show only one of individual-filled graphs, so this requires load only schema graph and individual-filled graph itself.